# NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array When I am trying to access a folder inside assets in android studio

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, assets

in my android project I have added a folder inside assets called validator. Inside validator folder there are some json files.
I want to access them and then manage these files with

```
File[] files = f.listFiles
```

When I am running the application I get the following error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of
> null array

I am assuming that the issue here is the path I am providing. The project structure is the following:

```
MyApplication    
│
└───app
    │
    └───src
        │
        └───main
            │
            └───res
            │
            └───assets
            │
            └───java
                │
                └───Main activity
```

So, inside main activity I have created a path containing the string and then

```
    File f = new File(path); 
    File[] files = f.listFiles
```

But the result is an error saying that the array is null.
The path I have provided is :

```
String path = "..\\MyApplication\\app\\src\\main\\assets";
```

Finally, I have added the permission in the manifest regarding the external storage

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Is the path incorrect or is there another issue?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Until someone provides a proper answer I'd take a look at the [getAssets()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getAssets()) method and the [AssetManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager). You might need to use those as file system access in Android is somewhat limited. The path you use might work in a desktop Java app. but not in Android.

Comment: You cannot use the File class for files in assets resource.

Comment: What's the alternative?

Comment: This is not the way you access files in Android. Google how to do it, but this is old Java way that works on desktop.